# How can I pass select-option value of the html code into the php file by javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My script code is for ajax function in database.
The code is same as below.

```
 <script>
  function showUser(str)
  {
   .....
  }
  var selectedLang2 = document.getElementById('lang2').value;
  var selectedSubject1 = document.getElementById('subject1').value;
  xmlhttp.open("GET","db_"+selectedLang2+".php?q="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 } 
 </script>
```

According to above script code, script code only calls the php file which is selected-option value. So my select-option code is same as below

```
 <form>
 <select name="lang2" id="lang2">
    <option value="co">한국어</option>
    <option value="en">English</option>

    <option value="af">Afrikaans</option>

    <option value="ar">Arabic</option>
    .......
  </select>
  <select name="subject1" id="subject1">
     <option value="a">Infection : bacteria and virus </option>

     <option value="b">Infection : virus, fungus and etc</option>
     <option value="c">Malignant neoplasm</option>
      ----
  </select>
```

So I want to use php variables code(here is, `$lang1`, `$subject1`) as like below code.

```
  <?php
  $q = htmlspecialchars($_GET['q']);
  $lang2 = $REQUEST_['lang2'];
  $subject1 = $REQUEST_['subject1'];


  $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','autoset','my_db');
  if (!$con)
  ......
```

How have i to write script code.

```
 /*Here is target point.
  var selectedLang2 = document.getElementById('lang2').value;
  var selectedSubject1 = document.getElementById('subject1').value;
  xmlhttp.open("GET","db_"+selectedLang2+".php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send(); */
```

Please, give me a piece of advice.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send any info by GET without specifying the url parameters. But you can add extra parameters to the request url to achieve this.

Change your JS:

```
var selectedLang2 = document.getElementById('lang2').value;
var selectedSubject1 = document.getElementById('subject1').value;
xmlhttp.open("GET","db_" + selectedLang2 + ".php?q=" + str  + "&lang2=" + selectedLang2 + "&subject1=" + selectedSubject1,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Change your PHP:

```
$q = htmlspecialchars($_GET['q']);
$lang2 = htmlspecialchars($_GET['lang2']);
$subject1 = htmlspecialchars($_GET['subject1']);
```

Comment: Really i appreciate your kind reply very much.